# boilerplate starter file different

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app and after creation in `App.js` I should see `class App extends Component` similar to:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
 ;
```

I am seeing this as Default:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am following a tutorial and it clearly shows this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBws8MSXN7A)
I am using a newer version of node v10.15.3
and also `npm` 6.4.1 though I am not sure why the syntax would not follow clearly since it is `react`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of `create-react-app` (when you used `npx create-react-app` or similar action to bootstrap your app) and not on `node`/`npm`/`react` versions.

You can re-write the [`functional component` to `class component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) like so:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```